# Splitting arguments that have spaces

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a poll command for a bot, with the ability to set a title for the embed and a description (which will be the actual poll).

This is my code:

```
if (command === "pollvote") {
        if(!args.length){
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`You didn't give a question.`)
            .setColor(`#245ebd`)
            message.channel.send(embed)
            return
        }

        var arguments = args.toString();
        arguments = arguments.split(",")

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(arguments[0])
        .setColor(`#245ebd`)
        .setThumbnail(`https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/960395119809429584/976463843008086146/Videostreamers_logo_nieuw_pink3.2.png?width=666&height=666`)
        .setDescription(arguments[1])

        message.channel.send(embed).then(sentEmbed => {
            sentEmbed.react("")
            sentEmbed.react("")
        });
    }
```

The code doesn't error when running the command nor when launching the bot. The only issue is that it doesn't do the job properly

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you were trying to do...

```js
var arguments = args.join(" ").split(",");

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(arguments[0])
.setColor(`#245ebd`)
.setThumbnail(`https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/960395119809429584/976463843008086146/Videostreamers_logo_nieuw_pink3.2.png?width=666&height=666`)
.setDescription(arguments[1])
```

when you were doing `args.toString()`, it did nothing. what this does is `join` the args together, and then split them at the comma. `arguments[0]` will return what comes before the comma, and `arguments[1]` will return what comes after the comma.